# How to format Serilog JSON output in a very specific manner

Tags: c#, serilog

I need to format the Serilog json output to file in a very specific format. I've messed with the outputtemplate but I must be missing something simple. An example of the output is:

```
{ 
    "event.action": "Save",
    "custom.vulnerability": "Save PII",
    "event.action":"Insert",
    "event.module":"Person",
    "message":"Inserted person object by Bob",
    "event.outcome":"Success",
    "host.ip":"192.168.0.0",
    etc...
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this format? I have enrichers to populate many of these properties but producing the desired output format is my issue. Thanks, Donta

Comment: Might be a use case to just create your own sink where you have direct programmatic control

Comment: hello! check this link. It may help you to do something near of what you want https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact

Comment: https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/programmable-serilog-formatting/ shows how Serilog.Expressions can be used for this, and should be much quicker than taking the customer format route (if you don't need indented JSON output :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to control the format of the JSON output you'll need to implement a custom [`ITextFormatter`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#formatting-json) (where you decide how to format the JSON), and provide it to the sink(s) that are emitting the logs.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.File(new YourCustomJsonFormatter(), "./logs/myapp.json")
  .CreateLogger();
```

You can see an example implementation of a custom `ITextFormatter` in the source code of [Serilog.Formatting.Compact](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact).

Comment: I implemented a custom formatter and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the suggestions!